# Midline Shortcut for VI?

Tags: cursor-movement

Is there a shortcut to take you to the midpoint or the middle of a line inside VI? Ctrl + A and Cntrl + E are super helpful, but I'd love something that's Cntrl + M or something to take me to the line middle.

For example, if I make a spelling error in the following fictional command, it might be nice to have my cursor go to the bold (or near it) in order to fix the error rather than having to press the left or right arrow so many times

```
I am a terminal command **z**with a spelling error
```

Comment: `f`, `z` maybe?

Comment: If your question is about vim, then I think `gM` does what you want. I don't think it's available in either readline's or zsh' vi-mode though. **Edit**: looks like it's only available since version 8.1.2231 too (see [the changelog](https://vimhelp.org/version8.txt.html)).

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , or [vi.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: This question is appropriate for [vi.se] and @Marth you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In vim, you can navigate spelling errors with `]s` and `[s`. That doesn’t address moving to the middle of the line, but it’s more efficient to go exactly where you need, no ?